# Web service call fails with RESTClient

Tags: java, restful-url, rest-client

I have a web service developed using Eclipse. Now I want to test it using RESTClient program. I want the client to download the video, which I have defined like this in Eclipse:

```
@Path("/university")
public class Video {
  //this is the location of the .avi
  private static final String VIDEO_FILE = "F:\\file.avi";

  @GET
  @Path("/video")
  @Produces("video/avi")
  public Response getVideoFile() {
    File file = new File(VIDEO_FILE);
    ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) file);

    response.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"abc.avi\"");
    return response.build();
  }

  @GET
  @Path("/{fileName}/video")
  @Produces("video/avi")
  public Response getFileInVideoFormat(@PathParam("fileName") String fileName) {
    System.out.println("File requested is : " + fileName);

    if (fileName == null || fileName.isEmpty()) {
      ResponseBuilder response = Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST);
      return response.build();
    }

    File file = new File("c:/abc.avi");

    ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) file);
    response.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=abc.avi");
    return response.build();
  }
}
```

but I am getting errors when I test using RESTClient (where I specify `METHOD=GET, HEADER(key=accept,value=video/avi)`). What might the problem?

Comment: Please post the exact error message(s) as well.

Comment: And your client code

Comment: As I have I am trying to test my webservice before I code the client part of it. I am using a a program i downloaded from https://code.google.com/p/rest-client/downloads/list just to test if its going to work well. But I am encountering the error HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed  when I run it

Answer (score 0):

First, if your REST service does not `@Consume` something, you don't have to specify "Accept" parameter in header (see HTTP request specification).

Second, your call should look like `contextpath/university/video` or `contextpath/university/filename/video`.

Third, don't use ambiguous REST paths like `/video` and `/{anystring}/video`, your application server can understand your calls wrong. Use patterns (for example `/{id:[0-9]+`) or rename `/{filename}/video` to `/video/{filename}` to avoid ambiguousness.